# NHibernate QueryOver with leftjoins

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, queryover

This thing is keeping me busy for days and I hope someone of the NHibernate gurus can help me out. I've got a query set up which is working in SQL Server and I want to get the same in NHibernate. But all my tries (did a lot of googeling and browsing in stackoverflow) failed so far. Here's the query:

```
Select
  j.id,
  j.title,
  j.company,
  jt.name as category,
  loc.city,
  je.is_assigned,
FROM job j
  LEFT JOIN location loc ON loc.id = j.location
  LEFT JOIN job_tag jt ON jt.job = j.id
    and jt.name in (SELECT name FROM tag WHERE tag_category=''Jobtype'')
  LEFT JOIN job_employee je ON je.job = j.id
    and je.employee_uid = <string>
```

I would prefer to use QueryOver but would be happy to get recommendations from you guys!

EDIT: What I do have so far is pretty simple...

```
JobEmployee jobEmployee = null;
Location loc = null;
JobTag jobTag = null;

session.QueryOver<Job>()
  .JoinAlias(x => x.location, () => loc)
  .JoinAlias(x => x.tags, () => jobTag, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin,
     Restrictions.On(jobTag.name).IsIn(<subquery>))
  .List();
```

But there are errors like "delegate .... does not take 1 arguments".

Best regards,
Martin

Comment: Look, query over syntax for this scenario is pretty well described here http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover. It would be nice if you can do something. Basic JOIN, SELECT, WHERE - show what you have, and describe what is not working ... if anything. It'll be a much more easier for someone NHibernate-experienced to give you help.

Comment: I have no issue with basic NHibernate usage. I know how to set up selects, where clauses etc. But I don't have an idea how to set the condition to the left join. Hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: Great job. More errors would help, but let me check this. Or maybe some other will give the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a draft of the solution... First the subquery:

```
var subquery = QueryOver
    .Of<Tag>()
    .Where(t => t.TagCategory == "Jobtype")
    .Select(t => t.Name);
```

And now, we will use the subquery in the `withClause`:

```
JobEmployee jobEmployee = null;
Location loc = null;
JobTag jobTag = null;

var list = session
  .QueryOver<Job>()
  .JoinAlias(x => x.location, () => loc)
  .JoinAlias(x => x.tags, () => jobTag, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin,

  // instead of this
  // Restrictions.On(jobTag.name).IsIn(<subquery>))

  // use this
    Subqueries.WhereProperty(() => jobTag.name).In(subquery)
  )
  .List();
```

So, we filtered the JOIN using the **withClause** and `Subqueries`

Comment: Thanks for the subquery, this lead me into the right direction. However, when I try to add another condition to the first JoinAlias like 'JoinAlias(x => x.location, () => loc, Restrictions.Equals(loc.name,"<myplace>"))', the compiler tells me that 'Delegate....does not take 1 arguments' for x => x.location. Without the Criterion it works like charm :-/ Any suggestions?

Comment: Try the `.JoinAlias(x => x.location, () => loc, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin, Restrictions.Eq("name", "<myplace>"))`. That should be correctly translated

Comment: Amazing!!! I was digging yesterday the whole evening to find documentations/examples that are explaining this topic better. Not successful so far... any chance that you explain why my approach failed? Why does the Criterion require an expression instead of the bool Restrictions.Equals?

Comment: Well ;) I do not know how to answer the "why" ;) But luckily we do have the answer for you "how to"... Enjoy NHibernate. It is amazing tool. Really