# Is it possible to have a subselect in the join part in Nhibernate QueryOver?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, queryover

I am trying to duplicate

```
Select
    ...
From Mistress Mi
Left Outer Join Dog D On Mi.ID = C.MistressID
    And D.MasterID = 
        ( Select Ma2.ID From Master Ma2 Where 
            D.MasterID = Ma2.ID 
            And Ma2.Status = 42 )
Left Outer Join Master Ma On 
    D.MasterID = Master.ID 
    And Ma.Status = 42
```

What this means is that:
Give me all Mistresses regardless having a dog or not.
Give me all Masters that have Status
and all Dogs that are connected to said Masters and a Mistress.

This might result in only Mistresses.
But if we have a Dog, we are sure it's Master has Status.

It is the subselect in the join that eludes me.
All my tries with `WithSubQuery` results in the subselect added to the final Where clause (and not inside the Join part as I want).

Is it even possible with NHibernate/QueryOver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible. When we do `JoinAlias` *(JOIN statement)*, we can pass the 4th parameter, so called with clause. In this Q & A:

- [NHibernate QueryOver with leftjoins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22631679/1679310)

We can see an example

```
var list = session
  .QueryOver<Job>()
  .JoinAlias(x => x.tags      // relation
     , () => jobTag,          // alias
     , JoinType.LeftOuterJoin // type
     , Subqueries.WhereProperty(() => jobTag.name).In(subquery) // here
  )
  .List();
```

that 4th paramter is added into `ON` cluase with `AND` *(it could just restrict more the existing relation conditions)*